# How to get an angle using tangent

Tags: c#, angle

I have a triangle, knowing lenghts of two sides (see picture) and need to know an angle shown in the picture (red are known, the blue angle is what I need to count)

[image]

I found out, that Math.Tan gets me the angle expressed in radians, so when I tried to do this:

```
alpha = Math.Tan((CA/AB));
```

I always get 0 as a result.
My question is - how can i get this angle, knowing only these two sides?

Comment: How is `alpha` defined? Is it an `int` or a `double`?

Comment: As a `double`, because when i tried with `int` I got error when debugging.

Comment: And lengths are double too?

Comment: I think more importantly, what types are CA and AB?

Comment: No, they weren't. Now after changing them to double, it works :) Thanks

Comment: `Math.Tan` _takes_ the angle in radians and gives the ratio (in your case) `CA/AB`. You need `Math.Atan` (or better, `Math.Atan2`, as given in one of the answers below).

Comment: @MarekBuchtela "Now after changing them to double, it works" It produces a non-zero number, yes, but it does not mean that it "works": what you get back is a tangent of a tangent, not the angle that you need. Try this with `AB` and `CA` of equal length: you should get `π/4` or `0.785`, but you get `1.557` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
double alpha = Math.Atan2(CA, AB)
```

Make sure the result, `alpha`, and other variable are `double`

Comment: @bash.d No, this is the right answer: the OP wants to know the angle, and `Atan2` is precisely how you get an angle from two sides of a right triangle.

Answer (score 4):

My psychic debugging tells me that `CA` and `AB` are both integers, either `int` or `long`.  The result will therefore also be an integer type, truncating any decimal value as needed.  Convert at least one of the values to a floating point type to get a floating point result:

```
alpha = Math.Tan((CA/(double)AB));
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP needs arctan, not tangent.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard He may need that changed as well, but this will get him past his immediate programming problem and onto his geometrical problem.

Comment: You need to use arctanjant instead of tanjant as Servy mentioned above. Look at my answer.

Comment: `CA/(double)AB` (or the opposite side divided by the adjacent side) is already a tangent; there is no need to pass it to `Math.Tan`

Answer (score 2):

The angle that you are looking for is arctanjant not tanjant.

So you should use the arctanjant function of .Net library. The following line gives what you need.

```
double alpha = Math.Atan ((double)CA/AB) * 180 / PI;
```

where PI is 3.14 as you know.

Comment: Use `Math.PI` rather than rounding to 3.14.